# JsonPlaceHolder multiple api call using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api

I am very new to angular js and I have been hanging around with api. The following code shows the name of the user and the name of the user when it is clicked. What I'm trying to do is I want the user to get the todos title when the button is clicked. https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos. how can I do that ? I know it's a bit confusing, but I'm waiting for you guys.

jsonplaceholder.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"> 
</script>
<script src="script.js"></script>

<head>
<title>JsonPlaceHolder</title>
</head>

<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 

<ul>
 <li ng-repeat="x in myData">
    {{ x.name }}

<button ng-click="getResult($index)">Click</button>
 </li>
 </ul>

<h2>Results</h2>
  <p><code>Title : </code> {{indexResult.name}}</p> 
 </div>
 </body>
   </html>
```

script.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
var root = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
$http.get(root).then(function (response) {
  $scope.myData = response.data;
});
 $scope.getResult = function($index) {
 $scope.indexResult = $scope.myData[$index];

};
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write your code like this:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
var root = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';
var todos= 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos'
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

$http.get(root).then(function (response) {
  $scope.myData = response.data;
});
   $scope.getResult = function(item) {
      $scope.titleList = [];
      $http.get(todos).then(function (response) {
      $scope.todosList = response.data; }).then(()=> {
      $scope.todosList.map(it=> {
      if (it.userId === item.id){
         $scope.titleList.push({title: it.title , id: it.userId});
      }   
   });
});
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="app.js"></script>

<head>
<title>JsonPlaceHolder</title>
</head>

<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 

<ul>
 <li ng-repeat="x in myData">
    {{ x.name }}

<button ng-click="getResult(x)">Click</button>
 </li>
 </ul>

<h2>Results</h2>
 
    <ul>
   <li ng-repeat="item in titleList">
  {{ item.title }}
   </li>
 </ul>
 </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for this code! . But the code is incomplete. Because it only brings one title. However, the user has 20 titles. why does not it show other titles?

Comment: I edit it for you. to show all title based on userId